# Need to convert wkb_geometry or x y in .csv file to latitude and longitude

Tags: csv, spreadsheet, latitude-longitude, google-fusion-tables

On this site http://data.kk.dk/dataset/monumenter/resource/1cb3ccdf-b939-4f41-8805-7e45832e9756 you can download monumenter.csv but I need a columne ALSO for latitude and longitude so I can upload this .CSV-file to use in FusionTables. Can someone tell me how to do this the easiest way?
I have tried open it up in Spreadsheet can copy the data and pasted this in these 2 manually made column but can't get the correct decimal for latitude and longitude to show correct in my Spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

The correct latitude and longitude are in the wkb_geometry column.

```
FID          | wkb_geometry                                  | id | navn           | loebenummer | web_id | x      | y
monumenter.1 | POINT (12.563269688605702 55.674194067522194) | 1  | frihedsstøtten | 54          | 24     | 724046 | 6175575
```

the coordinates are:

```
longitude = 12.563269688605702
latitude =  55.674194067522194
```

[exported kml from FUsionTable](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/monumenter.kml)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I know the coordinates are in wbk_geometry but HOW do I make the decimal and numbers show correct in new column for latitude and longitude that I made manually and paste in the numbers in my excel file, thats the question?

I get this http://tinemuller.dk/div/locations_wrong.jpg and this will NOT work when I upload to FusionTables.
On your great map in infowindow you have reversed latand lng numbers. :-)

Comment: Just change the names of the columns.  The format of POINT is POINT (longitude, latitiude)